# Problem with apache2 in error.log apache 2 can not start?

Tags: linux, unix, debian

I'm blocked on apache 2 it won't start

This is the code error:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Thank' s for any help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you paste the full/relevant config here?

Comment: The error tell you that first line of the configuration file has invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

i resolve my situation on re install my server and apache2 surely a error of syntax but more quickly to reinstall it that to find the error
Have a nice day